# I want to write a powershell script which will open cmd and execute the desired command

Tags: powershell, cmd

basically i want to open any window application and want to input any command through script.
I want to write a powershell script which will open cmd and execute the desired command.
i am able to start cmd using powershell but not able to pass command.
 eg i want to open cmd using powershell and execute copy command on cmd .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the file specifically in cmd you can use cmd with switch `/c` to execute the command you want:

```
cmd /c copy C:\Temp\abcd.txt C:\Temp\abcd2.txt
```

On the other hand you can easily achieve the same functionality using Powershell's `Copy-Item` command:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\Temp\abcd.txt -Destination C:\Temp\abcd2.txt
```